# Dealing with JSON interop between Java and C# REST APIs

Tags: java, c#, json, spring-boot, json.net

I'm currently dealing with 2 systems that expose interop via their own RESTful JSON APIs. One is in C# with JSON.NET and one is Java Spring Boot Starter (Jackson JSON). I have full control over both systems.

Both systems need to transfer JSON data with reference handling. Whilst both JSON serialization frameworks support it, C# JSON.NET uses `"$id"` and `"$ref"` syntax to signify references whilst Java's Jackson uses something plainer with only `"id"`.

I am much less familiar with Java than I am C# so I would more readily accept and understand any solution on getting JSON ref handling working both ways on the C# side. How can I get these two systems to interop with JSON refs?

[C# JSON.NET reference handling documentation.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm)

### Example JSON coming from Java Jackson

Note that it is possible to mark up what class property Jackson uses as the reference. In this case I am using the `Id` variable as it will always locally unique to the type.

```
{
  "Resources": [
      {
          "Id": 0,
          "Name": "Resource 0"
      },
      {
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Resource 1"
      }
  ],
  "Tasks": [
      {
          "Id": 0,
          "Name": "Task 0",
          "Resource": 0
      },
      {
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Task 1",
          "Resource": 1
      },
      {
          "Id": 2,
          "Name": "Task 2",
          "Resource": 0
      },
      {
          "Id": 3,
          "Name": "Task 3",
          "Resource": 1
      },
      {
          "Id": 4,
          "Name": "Task 4",
          "Resource": 0
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for a solution on the [tag:c#] side, we need to see the JSON you need to serialize and deserialize as c# folks may not know Java & Jackson.  A [mcve] showing the JSON to be exchanged would be ideal.

Comment: I've added an example JSON.

Comment: Is [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491595/how-can-i-make-reference-handling-syntax-from-jackson-and-json-net-compatible) helpful?

Comment: I'm afraid not - The solution only supports a single type AFAIK and it is only one-way - IE Jackson -> C#, and doesn't implement C# -> Jackson.

Comment: would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60158588/10422932) answer your question?

Comment: Will the data always be in this format? A wrapper composed of two lists, where all references are known after processing the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Before reading**, check out my other solution approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64235513/2355482), it may be simpler.
Keeping this post as well as I believe it is informative and may be consider a better approach by some.

---

### Why is this complicated?

The issue is not the reference property names, for that you can use `IReferenceResolver` to override. Instead, the issue is two-fold:

1. The reference is from a property of an object in the `Tasks` list to an object in the `Resources` list. This is not the intention of the `PreserveObjectReference` feature. It was intended to not repeat objects in the same list as well as help prevent cyclic references.
2. The value in the `Resource` property of a `Task` is a number instead of a `Resource` object (which would not have worked anyways, due to item 1 above), e.g.

```json
{
  "Id": 0,
  "Name": "Task 0",
  "Resource": {
    "$ref": 0
  }
}
```

3. IDs and references have to be strings, not numbers

---

### Solution

Manually build the object and manually match the references:

1. Our DTOs:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    public Resource[] Resources { get; set; }
    public Task[] Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

2. Contract resolution:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This is to resolve the Resource resolver for the Task
/// </summary>
internal class TaskResourceContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly IDictionary<long, Resource> _resources;

    public TaskResourceContractResolver(IDictionary<long, Resource> resources) => this._resources = resources;

    #region Overrides of DefaultContractResolver
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.DeclaringType != typeof(Task) || property.PropertyName != nameof(Task.Resource))
            return property;

        property.Converter = new TaskResourceConverter(this._resources);
        property.IsReference = true;
        property.ValueProvider = new CurrentValueGetterValueProvider();
        return property;
    }
    #endregion Overrides of DefaultContractResolver

    /// <summary>
    /// This is to resolve the Resource for the Task
    /// </summary>
    private class TaskResourceConverter : JsonConverter<Task>
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<long, Resource> _resources;

        public TaskResourceConverter(IDictionary<long, Resource> resources) => this._resources = resources;

        #region Overrides of JsonConverter
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Task value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override Task ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Task existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.Value is Resource resource) existingValue.Resource = resource;
            else if (reader.Value is long resourceRef)
            {
                if (!this._resources.TryGetValue(resourceRef, out resource)) throw new Exception($"Invalid resource reference '{resourceRef}'");
                existingValue.Resource = resource;
            }
            else throw new Exception($"Invalid resource reference '{reader.Value}'");

            return existingValue;
        }
        #endregion Overrides of JsonConverter
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is so we get the value of Task object to be set
    /// </summary>
    private class CurrentValueGetterValueProvider : IValueProvider
    {
        #region Implementation of IValueProvider
        public void SetValue(object target, object value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public object GetValue(object target) => target;
        #endregion Implementation of IValueProvider
    }
}
```

3. Implementation:

```cs
var input = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.input); // the posted Java-outputted JSON
var parsed = JObject.Parse(input);

var resources = parsed[nameof(Dto.Resources)]?.Children()
    .Select(token => token.ToObject<Resource>())
    .ToDictionary(r => r!.Id);

var serializer = new JsonSerializer() { ContractResolver = new TaskResourceContractResolver(resources) };

var dto = new Dto
{
    Resources = resources?.Values.ToArray(),
    Tasks = parsed[nameof(Dto.Tasks)]?.Children()
        .Select(token => token.ToObject<Task>(serializer))
        .ToArray()
};

Console.WriteLine($@"Distinct resources: {dto.Resources?.Distinct().Count()}");
Console.WriteLine($@"Distinct tasks: {dto.Tasks?.Distinct().Count()}");
Console.WriteLine($@"Distinct task resources: {dto.Tasks?.Select(t => t.Resource).Distinct().Count()}");
```

4. Output:

```
Distinct resources: 2
Distinct tasks: 5
Distinct task resources: 2
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9QNXLi)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a simpler approach to what I published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215759/2355482)

Reasons are the same, but solution is different:

**Use an interim serialization-only class**

(this one has both serialization and deserialization solution)

1. DTOs are the same:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    public Resource[] Resources { get; set; }
    public Task[] Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

2. Interim serialization-only class:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for Dto serialization
/// </summary>
internal class DtoSerializationHelper
{
    public Resource[] Resources { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// To be used by application code (not for 
    /// </summary>
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Task[] Tasks { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used by serializer
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty(nameof(Tasks))]
    private TaskSerializationHelper[] SerializationTasks { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        var resourceLookup = this.Resources.ToDictionary(r => r.Id);
        this.Tasks = this.SerializationTasks.Select(t => t.ToTask(resourceLookup)).ToArray();
    }

    [OnSerializing]
    private void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.SerializationTasks = this.Tasks?.Select(t => new TaskSerializationHelper(t)).ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts from the helper to the Dto when casting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper"></param>
    public static implicit operator Dto(DtoSerializationHelper helper) => new Dto
    {
        Resources = helper.Resources,
        Tasks = helper.Tasks
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts from the Dto to the helper when casting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dto"></param>
    public static explicit operator DtoSerializationHelper(Dto dto) => new DtoSerializationHelper
    {
        Resources = dto.Resources,
        Tasks = dto.Tasks
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// A Task serialization helper class
    /// </summary>
    private class TaskSerializationHelper
    {
        public TaskSerializationHelper() { }

        public TaskSerializationHelper(Task task) : this()
        {
            this.Id = task.Id;
            this.Name = task.Name;
            this.Resource = task.Resource.Id;
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long Resource { get; set; }

        public Task ToTask(IDictionary<long, Resource> resourceLookup) =>
            new Task
            {
                Id = this.Id,
                Name = this.Name,
                Resource = resourceLookup is null || !resourceLookup.TryGetValue(this.Resource, out var resource)
                    ? throw new Exception($"Invalid resource {this.Resource}")
                    : resource
            };
    }
}
```

3. Implementation:

```cs
var input = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.input); // the posted Java-outputted JSON

var dtoSerializationHelper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DtoSerializationHelper>(input);
var dto = (Dto)dtoSerializationHelper;

var deserializationResults = new
{
    distinctResources = dto.Resources?.Distinct().Count(),
    distinctTasks = dto.Tasks?.Distinct().Count(),
    distinctTaskResources = dto.Tasks?.Select(t => t.Resource).Distinct().Count()
};

Console.WriteLine($@"Distinct resources: {deserializationResults.distinctResources}");
Console.WriteLine($@"Distinct tasks: {deserializationResults.distinctTasks}");
Console.WriteLine($@"Distinct task resources: {deserializationResults.distinctTaskResources}");

if (deserializationResults.distinctResources != 2 ||
    deserializationResults.distinctTasks != 5 ||
    deserializationResults.distinctTaskResources != 2) throw new Exception("Deserialization failed");

Console.WriteLine();

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((DtoSerializationHelper)dto);
var serializationResult = output == input;

Console.WriteLine($@"Input and output are same: {serializationResult}");
if (serializationResult) return;

Console.WriteLine($@"Output: {output}");
throw new Exception("Serialization failed");
```

4. Output:

```
Distinct resources: 2
Distinct tasks: 5
Distinct task resources: 2

Input and output are same: True
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zyeih3)